# Ariṣṭhā and Pradhā

Tags: gods, apsaras

I've compared these two wives of Kaśyapa, Ariṣṭhā and Pradhā, and it seems like they're both said to have given birth to the Apsaras Alambuṣā, Miśrakeśī, Vidyutparṇā, etc.

Are these different sets of Apsaras with the same names or are these two wives identical?

Comment: First of all, the mother of the Apsaras was Muni, neither Arishta nor Pradha. Secondly, Arishta is the wife of Kashyapa who gave birth to the Gandharvas, not the Apsaras. Thirdly, neither Arishta nor Pradha are Apsaras. And from where did you get that Pradha is the name of one of Kashyapa’s wives?

Comment: https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/apsaras

"Ariṣṭhā, a wife of Kaśyapa, delivered thirteen Apsaras. They were: Alambuṣā, Miśrakeśī, Vidyutparṇā, Tilottamā, Rakṣitā, Rambhā, Manoramā, Keśinī, Subāhu, Surajā, Suratā and Supriyā. Ariṣṭhā gave birth also to four Gandharvas, Hāhā, Hūhū, Atibāhu and Tumburu as mentioned in the following verse.

"ariṣṭāsūta subhagādevī devarṣitaḥ purā alambuṣā miśrakeśī vidyutparṇā tilottamā aruṇā rakṣitā caiva rambhā tadvat manoramā keśinī ca subāhuśca vikhyatau ca hahāhuhū tumburuśceti catvāraḥ smṛtāḥ gandharvasattamāḥ." (Puranic Encyclopedia, p. 46)

Comment: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/compilation/puranic-encyclopaedia/d/doc242006.html

"Tilottamā was born to Pradhā, wife of Kaśyapa, grandson of Brahmā and son of Marīci. Alambuṣā, Miśrakeśī, Vidyutparṇā, Aruṇā, Rakṣitā, Rambhā, Manoramā, Subāhu, Keśinī, Suratā, Surajā and Supriyā were all sisters of Tilottamā. (Chapter 65, Ādi Parva)."

...Although this source gives Chapter 215 of the Ādi Parva Viśvakarmā to claim that Viśvakarmā was the one who created Tilottamā.